# SQL Nested query interpereted as correlated incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've got a serious problem with a nested query, which I suspect MySQL is interpreting as a correlated subquery when in fact it should be uncorrelated.  The query spans two tables, one being a list of products and the other being their price at various points in time.  My aim is to return each price record for products that have a price range above a certain value for the whole time.  My query looks like this:

```
SELECT oP.id, oP.title, oCR.price, oC.timestamp
FROM Crawl_Results AS oCR
        JOIN Products AS oP 
            ON oCR.product = oP.id
        JOIN Crawls AS oC 
            ON oCR.crawl = oC.id
WHERE oP.id
IN (
    SELECT iP.id
    FROM Products AS iP
            JOIN Crawl_Results AS iCR 
               ON iP.id = iCR.product
    WHERE iP.category =2
    GROUP BY iP.id
    HAVING (
              MAX( iCR.price ) - MIN( iCR.price )
           ) >1
)
ORDER BY oP.id ASC
```

Taken alone, the inner query executes fine and returns a list of the id's of the products with a price range above the criterion.  The outer query also works fine if I provide a simple list of ids in the IN clause.  When I run them together however, the query takes ~3min to return ~1500 rows, so I think it's executing the inner query for every row of the outer, which is not ideal.  I did have the columns aliased the same in the inner and outer queries, so I thought that aliasing them differently in the inner and outer as above would fix it, but it didn't.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL might think it could use indexes to execute the query faster by running it once for every `OP.id`.  The first thing to check is if [your statistics are up to date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html).

You could rewrite the `where ... in` as a filtering `inner join`.  This is less likely to be "optimized" for seeks:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Crawl_Results AS oCR
JOIN    Products AS oP 
ON      oCR.product = oP.id
JOIN    Crawls AS oC 
ON      oCR.crawl = oC.id
JOIN    (
        SELECT  iP.id
        FROM    Products AS iP
        JOIN    Crawl_Results AS iCR 
        ON      iP.id = iCR.product
        WHERE   iP.category =2
        GROUP BY 
                iP.id
        HAVING  (MAX(iCR.price) - MIN(iCR.price)) > 1
        ) filter
ON      OP.id = filter.id
```

Another option is to use a temporary table.  You store the result of the subquery in a temporary table and join on that.  That really forces MySQL not to execute the subquery as a correlated query.

Comment: Perfect!  Now executes in 0.018s rather than 150s!